# b-form-select get selected option as value

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I'm having some trouble understanding b-form-select from bootstrap-vue.

I have a list of object lets say

```
factories = [{ id: 1, name: "A" }, { id: 2, name: "B" }]`
```

And my select as

```
<b-form-select
  v-model="factory"
  :options="factories"
  value-field="id"
  text-field="name"
/>
```

But how would I do to get the full selected object rather than just the `id` without having to declare options manually ?

This works but it feels 'hacky'.

```
<b-form-select v-model="factory">
  <option v-for="f in factories" :value="f" :key="f.id">{{f.name}}</option>
</b-form-select>
```

If not possible, any reasons why ?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work because `<b-form-select>` requires the options array to take the form of:

```
[{value: factory, text: factory.name}]
```

Put another way, `<b-form-select>` doesn't know what to do with `[{id: 1, name: 'A'}]`

To make your first form work, you'll need to transform the array 'factories' into an array the  can use:

```
const factories = [{ id: 1, name: "A" }, { id: 2, name: "B" }]

var factoriesSelectList = []

factories.forEach((factory, index, mechanicsArray) => {
    var selectListOption = {
       value: factory,
       text:  factory.name
    }

    factoriesSelectList.push(selectListOption)
})
```

Then, in your template:

```
<b-form-select
  v-model="factory"
 :options="factoriesSelectList"
/>
```

**Note:** This probably isn't much different than doing it in the template as in your second form. I've not looked, but I'm betting the resulting javascript is similar.

Comment: You can tell b-form-select what keys to use as value and text via props: `value-field` to specify what property key to use for the value (i.e. `id`), and `text-field` for the text (i.e. `name`)

Comment: you could use `Array.map()` instead of `forEach`


eg: `factories.map((x) => { return { value: x.id, text: x.name });`